# How to install pylint for python2 and python3 side by side

Tags: python, virtualenv, pylint

I have a codebase that includes both python2 and python3 code.  I want to make one script that will run pylint on all python2 and all python3 files, ideally from within a single virtualenv.

I can figure out which version of pylint to run by annotating the directories (eg, adding a .pylint3 file to directories that need the python3 pylint to run or something like that).  However, I don't know how to install two separate versions of pylint side by side, either in the OS as a whole or in a virtualenv, without doing some manual annoying stuff.

Is there a good way to get two versions of pylint running side by side in the same virtualenv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually python modules for different major versions don't interfer with each other. The only problem is utilities. So the recipe is as follows:

1. Create a virtual environment for a python2, then go to the bin/ folder of the created environment and rename all created scripts/wrappers/binaries so that all of them would have suffix `2`
2. Repeat the creation of the virtual env. *in the same* directory but for python3. Again, go to the `bin/` subfolder of the created virtual environment and rename all newly created scripts to have suffix `3`.
3. Make sure that all hashbangs in the scripts call an apropriate python version.
4. Now you should `source <virtenv>/bin/activate` as the docs suggest
5. And now you may install pylint in the virtual env, you need to repeat the procedure for both python2 and python3, again separating the binaries in `<virtualenv>/bin/`. Use `pip2` and `pip3` or `python2 -m pip...`/`python3 -m pip...` for that.

I haven't installed pylint, but have an environment prepared for both python2 and python3 with a bunch of python utilities like `bpython` (called as `bpython2` and `bpython3` respectively, `pygmentize` etc). I don't think `pylint` is something different in this aspect.

Comment: Yeah, that should work, but it's doing the type of manual stuff I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Create a script, it shouldn't be too complex. Or simply use `python<ver> -m <utilmod>` if the utility supports that way of execution (pylint can be run as `python -m pylint ...`)

Answer (score 1):

I’m only addressing this part of your question:

> how to install two separate versions of pylint side by side, either in
>   the OS as a whole…

I already had an existing pylint installation (presumably from pip with Python 2), at `/usr/local/bin/pylint`, and a pip python3 installation in the same directory.

So I did the following:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/pylint ~/Back/    
pip3 install pylint
mv /usr/local/bin/pylint /usr/local/bin/pylint3
cp ~/Back/pylint  /usr/local/bin/pylint
```